What is the complete artificer infusion list?
The artificer from Eberron Campaign Setting can cast any infusion on its list that it has a spell slot for, without needing to prepare or learn it ahead of time. Is there a list anywhere of all those infusions, so artificers know what their options are?

While this list is very nearly complete, it is missing one infusion (invoke elemental from Explorer’s Handbook). Thus, for the sake of having a full-and-complete list available somewhere, the full list is:



Infusion
Level
Description
Source




Ablative Armor T
1st
Reduce damage from next attack by 5 + caster level (max 15).
MoE


Armor Enhancement, Lesser M T
1st
Armor or shield gains special ability with +1 bonus market price modifier.
EbCS


Energy Alteration M T
1st
Item using one kind of energy uses another instead.
EbCS


Enhancement Alteration T
1st
Magic shield’s enhancement bonus applies to shield bash attacks, or magic weapon’s enhancement bonus applies to Two-Weapon Defense.
EbCS


Entangling Dragonmark Dr
1st
Dragonmarked creature is entangled.
Dra


Identify M
1st
Determines properties of magic item.
PHB*


Indisputable Possession T
1st
Call an item back to your hand if it leaves your possession.
MoE


Inflict Light Damage
1st
Deals 1d8 + 1/level damage (maximum +5) to a construct.
EbCS


Knight Unburdened
1st
Remove the speed penalties for medium and heavy armor.
FoW


Light
1st
Object shines like torch.
PHB*


Magic Stone
1st
Three stones gain +1 on attack rolls, deal 1d6+1 damage.
PHB*


Magic Vestment
1st
Armor or shield gains +1 or better enhancement bonus.
PHB*


Magic Weapon
1st
Weapon gains +1 enhancement bonus.
PHB*


Metamagic Scroll
1st
Imbue spell completion item with metamagic feat.
MoE


Natural Weapon Augmentation, Personal
1st
One of your natural weapons gains special ability with +1 bonus market price modifier.
RoE


Pending Potion T
1st
Target potion or oil takes effect at a later time.
MoE


Repair Light Damage
1st
“Cures” 1d8 + 1/level damage (max +5) to a construct.
PHB*


Resistance Item T
1st
Item bestows +1 or better resistance bonus on saving throws.
EbCS


Shield of Faith
1st
Aura grants +2 or higher deflection bonus.
PHB*


Skill Enhancement T
1st
Item bestows circumstance bonus on skill checks.
EbCS


Spell Storing Item X T
1st
Store one spell in an item.
EbCS


Summon Marked Homunculus T Dr
1st
Summons a homunculus that explodes when destroyed.
Dra


Weapon Augmentation, Personal T
1st
Your weapon gains special ability with +1 bonus market price modifier.
EbCS








Align Weapon
2nd
Weapon becomes good, evil, lawful, or chaotic.
PHB*


Armor Enhancement M T
2nd
Armor or shield gains special ability with up to +3 bonus market price modifier.
EbCS


Bear’s Endurance
2nd
Subject gains +4 to Constitution for 1 min./level.
PHB*


Bull’s Strength
2nd
Subject gains +4 to Strength for 1 min./level.
PHB*


Cat’s Grace
2nd
Subject gains +4 to Dexterity for 1 min./level.
PHB*


Chill Metal
2nd
Cold metal damages those who touch it.
PHB*


Construct Essence, Lesser
2nd
Grants a living construct qualities of the construct type.
FoERoE


Eagle’s Splendor
2nd
Subject gains +4 to Charisma for 1 min./level.
PHB*


Elemental Prod T
2nd
Move an elemental creature a short distance.
MoE


Fox’s Cunning
2nd
Subject gains +4 to Intelligence for 1 min./level.
PHB*


Heat Metal
2nd
Make metal so hot it damages those who touch it.
PHB*


Ignite Dragonmark Dr
2nd
Target takes 1d6/level fire damage, has dragonmarked powers temporarily suppressed.
Dra


Inflict Moderate Damage
2nd
Deals 2d8 + 1/level damage (max +10) to a construct.
EbCS


Lucky Blade T
2nd
Weapon grants a single reroll of an attack.
MoE


Natural Weapon Augmentation, Lesser M T
2nd
Natural weapon gains special ability with +1 bonus market price modifier.
RoE


Owl’s Wisdom
2nd
Subject gains +4 to Wisdom for 1 min./level.
PHB*


Ray of Retaliation Dr
2nd
Ray attack is reflected back at its originator to deal force damage.
Dra


Repair Moderate Damage
2nd
“Cures” 2d8 + 1/level damage (max +10) to a construct.
EbCS


Reinforce Construct
2nd
Construct gains 1d6 + 1/level temporary hit points.
MoE


Suppress Dragonmark F T
2nd
Suppress the spell-like abilities of target’s dragonmark.
MoE


Swift Ready T
2nd
Enchant armor and weapons so that they appear on you instantly when you wish.
FoW


Toughen Construct
2nd
Grants construct +2 (or higher) enhancement to natural armor.
EbCS


Unseen Crafter
2nd
Invisible force obeys your command and can use the Craft skill.
RoE


Weapon Augmentation, Lesser M T
2nd
Weapon gains special ability with +1 bonus market price modifier.
EbCS








Adamantine Weapon T
3rd
Transform weapon into adamantine.
MoE


Armor Enhancement, Greater M T
3rd
Armor or shield gains special ability with up to +5 bonus market price modifier.
EbCS


Blast Rod T
3rd
Infused rod stores 1d8/level destructive energy.
MoE


Construct Energy Ward T
3rd
Construct gains resistance 10 to specified energy type.
EbCS


Dragonmarked Weapon Dr
3rd
Weapon deals +1d6 damage to dragonmarked foes, hardness increases by 50%.
Dra


Humanoid Essence, Lesser
3rd
Grants a construct the ability to accept healing magic.
RoE


Inflict Serious Damage
3rd
Deals 3d8 + 1/level damage (max +15) to a construct.
EbCS


Lucky Cape T
3rd
Cape grants a single reroll of a saving throw.
MoE


Magic Weapon, Greater
3rd
Weapon gains +2 or better enhancement bonus.
PHB*


Metamagic Item T
3rd
Imbue spell trigger item with metamagic feat.
EbCS


Power Surge X
3rd
Charged spell trigger item gains temporary charges.
EbCS


Repair Serious Damage
3rd
“Cures” 3d8 + 1/level damage (max +15) to a construct.
EbCS


Spell Snare T
3rd
Dragonshard absorbs a spell or spell-like ability of up to 3rd level.
MoE


Stone Construct M T
3rd
Construct gains DR 10/adamantine.
EbCS


Suppress Requirement M T
3rd
Item that requires class feature, race, ability score, or alignment to function to its fullest potential no longer carries that requirement.
EbCS








Censure Elementals
4th
Deal 2d4 + 1/level damage each round to elementals.
MoE


Concurrent Infusions T
4th
Cast three 1st-level infusions simultaneously.
MoE


Construct Energy Ward, Greater T
4th
Construct gains immunity to specified energy type.
EbCS


Globe of Invulnerability, Lesser
4th
Stops 1st- through 3rd-level effects.
PHB*


Humanoid Essence
4th
Imposes upon a construct some of the weaknesses of the humanoid type.
RoE


Inflict Critical Damage
4th
Deals 4d8 + 1/level damage (max +20) to a construct.
EbCS


Item Alteration T
4th
Item that provides a certain type of bonus provides a different type of bonus to the same value or roll.
EbCS


Iron Construct T
4th
Construct gains DR 15/adamantine and takes half damage from acid and fire.
EbCS


Minor Creation
4th
Create one cloth or wood object.
PHB*


Natural Weapon Augmentation M T
4th
Natural weapon gains special ability with up to +3 bonus market price modifier.
RoE


Repair Critical Damage
4th
“Cures” 4d8 + 1/level damage (max +20) to a construct.
EbCS


Rusting Grasp
4th
Your touch corrodes iron and alloys.
PHB*


Shield of Faith, Legion’s
4th
Allies gain +3 or higher AC bonus.
EbCS


Slaying Arrow T
4th
Creates a projectile deadly to a specific creature type.
EbCS


Weapon Augmentation M T
4th
Weapon gains special ability with up to +3 bonus market price modifier.
EbCS








Construct Essence
5th
As lesser construct essence, but grants more qualities of the construct type.
RoE


Disrupting Weapon
5th
Melee weapon destroys undead.
PHB*


Dominate Living Construct T
5th
As dominate person, but affecting a living construct.
RoE


Dragonmarked Weapon, Greater Dr
5th
Weapon deals +2d6 damage to dragonmarked foes, hardness is doubled.
Dra


Fabricate
5th
Transforms raw materials into finished items.
PHB*


Inflict Light Damage, Mass
5th
Deals 1d8 damage +1/level to many constructs.
RoE


Invoke Elemental
5th
Temporarily unbind elemental and have it fight for you.
ExH


Major Creation
5th
As minor creation, plus stone and metal.
PHB*


Repair Light Damage, Mass
5th
Repairs 1d8 damage +1/level to many constructs.
RoE


Wall of Force
5th
Wall is immune to damage.
PHB*


Wall of Stone
5th
Creates a stone wall that can be shaped.
PHB*








Blade Barrier
6th
Wall of blades deals 1d6/level damage.
PHB*


Construct essence, mass lesser
6th
Grants many living constructs qualities of the construct type.
FoE


Disable Construct
6th
Deals 10/level damage to target construct.
EbCS


Globe of Invulnerability
6th
As lesser globe of invulnerability, plus 4th-level spell effects.
PHB*


Hardening
6th
Item’s hardness increases by 1 per 2 levels.
PHB*


Humanoid Essence, Greater
6th
Gives a construct the humanoid type.
RoE


Inflict Moderate Damage, Mass
6th
Deals 2d8 damage +1/level to many constructs.
RoE


Move Earth
6th
Digs trenches and builds hills.
PHB*


Natural Weapon Augmentation, Greater M T
6th
Natural weapon gains special ability with up to +5 bonus market price modifier.
RoE


Repair Moderate Damage, Mass
6th
Repairs 2d8 damage +1/level to many constructs.
RoE


Spell Snare, Greater T
6th
Dragonshard absorbs a spell or spell-like ability of up to 6th level.
MoE


Total Repair
6th
Repair 10 points/level of damage to a construct.
EbCS


Wall of Iron M
6th
30 hp/four levels; can topple onto foes.
PHB*


Weapon Augmentation, Greater M T
6th
Weapon gains special ability with up to +5 bonus market price modifier.
EbCS




EbCS Eberron Campaign Setting
PHB* Player’s Handbook

* Note that the “infusions” from Player’s Handbook were printed as spells in that book, and assigned to the artificer as infusions in Eberron Campaign Setting.


MoE Magic of Eberron
FoE Faiths of Eberron
Dra Dragonmarked
ExH Explorer’s Handbook
FoW The Forge of War
RoE Races of Eberron

M Requires a costly material component.
X Requires XP component.
T Casting time of 1 round or more (cannot be completed the same turn it’s started).
Dr Requires a dragonmark, potentially of a certain kind.
Though many artificer infusions require costly material or XP components, bear in mind that the actual costs are often very low. Likewise, though many take a very-long time to cast, they can be sped up with an action point (or the Rapid Infusions feat), and also tend to last a decently-long time. Concurrent infusions can also cheat around a lot of those difficulties for 1st-level infusions.
I have it on fairly good authority—goes by @forrestfire here, much thanks—that Dragon and Dungeon magazine do not add any new artificer infusions. I have not checked this myself, and though @forrestfire has read through all the 3.5e issues of Dragon and Dungeon several times looking for stuff, infusions per se were never the specific goal of any of those trawls, so a slim possibility exists of there being a few.
